# How to extract only one file type within a .ZIP file on another directory

Tags: ruby, zip

Similar questions have been already asked before on this subject, but I'm unable to work it out. I have a batch of .ZIP files from which I only need to extract the .TXT files from all of them, and then move them to another location. I've tried this:

```
unzip test.zip '*.txt' #This would only be useful for extracting one single .ZIP file, not for each one.
```

And this:

```
require 'FileUtils'
require 'zip'
def unzip_file (file, destination)
Zip::File.open(file_path) { |zip_file| 
    zip_file.each { |f|
        f_path=File.join("destination_path", f.name) 
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path)) #Don't quite understand this line
        zip_file.extract(f, f_path) #Extraction is done here, but where?
    }
}
end
```

Neither option was successful, could you please suggest?

Comment: What went wrong with your second solution?

Comment: Nothing gets done. I don't even get an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method has a parameter `destination`, but it is never used.

Your code

```
          f_path=File.join("destination_path", f.name)
```

defines a folder named *destination_path* followed by the path of the file in the zip. Probably you want the content of the parameter `destination`.

With

```
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path))
```

you create the target path with all directories (a `mkdir` would only create one directory and if the parent directory does not exist you get an error).

In summary: Try this code:

```
require 'FileUtils'
require 'zip'
def unzip_file (file, destination)
  Zip::File.open(file_path) { |zip_file| 
      zip_file.each { |f|
          f_path=File.join(destination, f.name) 
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path)) 
          puts "Extract file to %s" % f_path
          zip_file.extract(f, f_path) 
      }
  }
end
```

---

After your comment:

To get only the txt-files inside the zip you can replace `each` with `glob`:

```
require 'zip' #Already loads FileUtils
#~ require 'FileUtils'

def unzip_file (file_path, destination)
  Zip::File.open(file_path) { |zip_file| 
      zip_file.glob('*.txt'){ |f|
          f_path=File.join(destination, f.name) 
          FileUtils.mkdir_p(File.dirname(f_path)) 
          puts "Extract file to %s" % f_path
          zip_file.extract(f, f_path) 
      }
  }
end
```

Then you can call the method for each zip-file in Folder_A and define the destination Folder_B:

```
Dir['Folder_A/*.zip'].each{|zipfile|
  unzip_file(zipfile, 'Folder_B')
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I might have omitted some information: The folder name with all the .ZIP files stored in it is always the same: `Folder_A`, and the folder where I want to extract the files is always called the same, `Folder_B`. Apart from this, I only need to extract .TXT files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now, I don't get any errors, though the operation is not done. I might have some issues when accessing the zip gem. My Ruby version is 2.1.7 and zip gem is rubyzip2. Should I install another gem?

Comment: are your txt-files in subfolders? Then you could try `**/*.txt`